# Add validation message in fieldset instead of js popup

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I have a php app, that has been pieced together, but I am working on an crazy validation piece, that i've got working.  At the end of the validation, the following function runs and gives me a popup with the listed of required fields.

```
function showReqFlds(emptyFlds) {
    for (var i = 0; i < emptyFlds.length; i++) {
    var holdErrMsgs = emptyFlds[i]+' is required.' + "\n";

    }
        alert(holdErrMsgs);
}
```

Works great, but now I want instead of the javascript popup box, I want the error messages to appear in a fieldset at the top of my form.

**Steps**:

User opens form, error fieldset is not displaying
User clicks the submit button to submit form, but has not filled in a couple of the required fields
Error fieldset appears, shows required field list, form is not submitted.

Any assistance would be appreciate.  Thank you.

Comment: i dont know what that function really do its makes really no sense to me

Comment: what have you tried? You need to replace your `alert` with code to insert your list into a DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think about this:

```
function changeText(text)
{
elem = document.getElementById('error_message');
elem.innerHTML = text;
}
```

And you have in your html page this:

```
 <div id='error_message'>I'm a error message</div>      
 <button onclick="changeText('error1');">error1</button>
 <button onclick="changeText('error2');">error2</button>
```

With something like this you should do the trick.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you can do this (if I understood your question).

```
function showReqFlds(emptyFlds) {
    for (var i = 0; i < emptyFlds.length; i++) {
       var holdErrMsgs = emptyFlds[i]+' is required.' + "\n";
    }
    //This is where you change
    header("location:yourpageurl.php?errorMsg=".holdErrMsgs);
}
```

Then, in yourpageurl.php, in the place that you want the message, you can do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['errorMsg']))
   echo $_GET['errorMsg'];
```

I hope it helps you!

Best.

Comment: Hummm, this is interesting - let me try. Thank you.