# Contact form: AJAX and jQuery animation and coding structure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I'm having this problem. Look at this: http://santz.net/index.contacto.html

Try sending whatever and see what happens (it's mine, I recieve it, send whatever no problem...). (It leaves the page, shows a dialog that says thanks for contacting us... and it redirects you to the same page). I HATE THIS!!!

I'm looking fore some AJAX and jQuery code that after the message is sent, it clears the form and opens a dialog (the common one... like the typical loggin boxes) and that fades the page and that show some "x" content...

The thing is that I don't know how to do any of this things and I'm driving crazy! If you could give me the code and tell me where to put it or just give a tutorial for noobs or something like that it would be great...

I leave here the PHP code I'm using:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['php_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['php_email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['php_phone'];
$field_message = $_POST['php_message'];

$field_sender = 'alpha@hotmail.com';

$mail_to = 'gama@hotmail.com.ar';
$subject = 'Mensaje via Santz.net de '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_sender."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Gracias por contactarse, en breve, me pondre en contacto.\n\nSantz Design | www.santz.net');
        window.location = 'index.contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('El envio fallo. Por favor, envie un mail directamente a info@santz.net');
        window.location = 'index.contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: are you trying to actual use  ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  or the below @RobertRozas redirect because your question seemed that you need more stuff then a redirect

Comment: David, I don't actually know what I need to get the result I described. I'll look for a website that implements this so that you can see that working... let me check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this:

```
window.location.assign('http://www.santz.net/');
```

instead of:

```
window.location = 'index.contacto.html';
```

Showing error message on the same page, follow this example:
[Add validation message in fieldset instead of js popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651957/add-validation-message-in-fieldset-instead-of-js-popup/14652771#14652771)

And for a modal windows, use a plugin like this one:

http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/my-jquery-plugins/modalpoplite

Demo:

http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/projects/modalpoplite/demo/

saludos ;)

Comment: Thanks Robert but that's not what I need... Actually, that's what I want to eliminate!

Comment: I think i understand....you want to get rid of the alert prompt...showing a message on the same page with a modal popup??

Comment: That's right! That message must show like here: http://www.pixeden.com/media-icons/soft-media-icons-set-vol-2

Clic on "Download" and you'll see that a beautifull box appears saying thatnks for downloading and whatever...

I want that but with my own content...

I don't know how to do it and what programming language to use

Comment: Great I'm trying this... I'll vote later... first check :)... Oh by the way... If I need any help would you help me? Thanks have a great day!

Comment: A hablas castellano entonces?

Comment: Buenisimo... estoy mirando mi código, y no entiendo una cosa... En la parte que me pusiste al principio de que cambie lo primero por lo segundo (en tu respuesta), para que me sirve eso? me redirecciona a la página principal? No quiero eso... no quiero que redireccione a ningún lado. Necesito que simplemente se borre todo lo que el usuario escribio y que aparezca esa modal box que me pasaste que está buenisima! Eso como lo hago?

Comment: Yo pensaba que querias redireccionar a la página principal....con el modal lo que tienes que hacer es un div wraper....es incluir los js y seguir el fuente del ejemplo: view-source:http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/projects/modalpoplite/demo/

Comment: Me dice aca el Stack Overflow que evite discusiones largas. Si queres y si no te estoy molestando ni sacando tiempo, te dejo mi página de Facebook: www.facebook.com/Santz.net y si me mandas vos un mensaje primero podemos chatear por ahi. Muchas gracais!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use jQuery

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: contact.php,
 data: $('#contact-form"').serialize();,
 success: function() {
   //modal
  }
 });
});
```

something along those lines would be the ajax way of submitting your form and then pop up a window to the user saying thanks please view [my form](http://codepen.io/davidchase/pen/znsEj) to get an idea just without popup

Comment: please do not ask about ajax coding if you do not know how to apply it, the question becomes missing leading

Comment: You could explin instead of attacking! I'm just 17 and I'm on my right to learn! Thanks a lot anyway!